# IoTHub Trigger function does not execute when new telemetry arrives

Tags: azure-functions, azure-iot-hub

I have an IoTHub Trigger (Event Hub Trigger) function that appears to operate for a period of time, and will then stop executing.  Restarting the Function App will show the buffered messages being processed as expected, but then the function will no longer trigger.

The Function App is running on a consumption plan and regularly receives telemtry messages from multiple devices (approximately 5 messages every 5 minutes).

I have searched our App Insights log and can find no warnings, or other messages that indicate a reason for the shutdown.  I do see Information messages indicating "DrainMode mode enabled", followed by a number of Information messages indicating that Listeners for each of our functions are being stopped:

DrainMode mode enabled

Calling StopAsync on the registered listeners

Stopping task hub worker. IsGracefulStop: False. InstanceId: . Function: . HubName: . AppName: . SlotName: Production. ExtensionVersion: 2.1.1. SequenceNumber: 2.

Stopping the listener '`Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.EventHubs.EventHubListener`' for function ''

Task hub worker stopped.

```
`IsGracefulStop: False. Latency: 00:00:00.2389180. InstanceId: . Function: . HubName: <myhubname>. AppName: <myfunctionappname>. SlotName: Production. ExtensionVersion: 2.1.1. SequenceNumber: 3
```

Stopped the listener '`Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.EventHubs.EventHubListener`' for function 'myfunctionname'

Call to StopAsync complete, registered listeners are now stopped

Any ideas why the listeners are shutting down, and how I can prevent it from happening?

Comment: Did you figure it out? I'm in the same boat...

Comment: Have you been able to find out anything here yet?
Unfortunately, I have exactly the same problem and do not know how to influence this behavior.